# How to manage images resolution in flutter app for both android and ios?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In Native ios and native android, 1x, 2x,3x images and mdpi, xdpi etc images sizes can use. For flutter app, how to manage this ?

If i use all those sizes, app size will be huge and also hard to manage. Otherwise if i use 1x size only for different device sizes, it will be shrinked or blurred.

Can anyone suggest me the solution for this ?

> Updated question :
> For each and every image, which sizes i can ask my UI/UX designer to provide for ios and android ?

Comment: If you using only for Android, these assets can directly be used as docs suggest here => https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use internet, converting pngs or jpgs to webp because it has less size than others. It may be good solution for you.

Comment: My question is not related to reduce size. Please check my comments in other answer

Answer (score 0):

Either you have an offline image or loading from the network. You just need to manage it on Screen Size.

You can give custom height and width to the image or parent widget to show accordingly screen resolutions.

Here is the different way to get width and height.

Getting **`width` is easy but `height` can be tricky**, following are the ways to deal with `height`

```
// Full screen width and height
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

// Height (without SafeArea)
var padding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding;
double height1 = height - padding.top - padding.bottom;

// Height (without status bar)
double height2 = height - padding.top;

// Height (without status and toolbar)
double height3 = height - padding.top - kToolbarHeight;
```

You can use width **/2** or **/3** for the width of the image and the same for height. It will work for Android, iOS, or other platforms too.

Do let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: My question is "if i use 80x80 sized image to 30x30 or 100x100 sized image to 200x200", then will be shrink or blur ? My point is for each and every image, my UI/UX designer which sized image need to provide to me ?